# Virtualenv is not creating a local pip and I really need it to

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Title says most. Here's what's going on...

```
~/project/path~$ python3 -m venv project-env
~/project/path~$ source project-env/bin/activate
(project-env) ~/project/path~$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3)
```

What the hell, shouldn't pip be loading from `~/project/path/project-env/bin/pip`?

```
(project-env) ~/project/path~$ ls -al project-env/bin/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 user  staff   170B Jun 30 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 user  staff   204B Jun 30 21:41 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user  staff   2.1K Jun 30 21:41 activate
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     7B Jun 30 21:41 python -> python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff    22B Jun 30 21:41 python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Ohhh, that's why, there's no local pip =(.

How can I configure the command `python3 -m venv project-env` to always load a local pip3? The fact pip isn't being loaded in by default is blasphemy.

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: You need to `activate` your virtual env: `source project-env/bin/activate`. Which version of `python3` are you running - prior to Py3.4 `pip` wasn't installed by default, just run `easy_install pip` to install it into your virtual env.

Comment: I have it activated, I forgot to add that snippet in my post though. I'll make an edit. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Prior to 3.4 I would just use the `virtualenv` package. Forgot you will need to run `ez_setup.py` to get `easy_install` installed.

Comment: I did a quick installation on Python-3.6 and got it working. It's interesting the python organization didn't want pip to be installed until version 3.4. Oh well. I'll run with 3.6 for now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Solution was found courtesy of [achampion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750492/achampion)'s comment. Python versions 3.4 and newer have this functionality. Using python3.6 for this task solved my issue.